# Angular $swipe.bind scroll issue

Tags: angularjs, swipe, angularjs-ng-touch

I have a page full with images and a ng-click on every image. 
The problem is that users can't scroll on touch devices.
I've tried to use the bind method of $swipe service. Here is my implementation:

```
$scope.seeDetails = function (key, title) {
   $swipe.bind(element, {
      start: function(){ console.log("start"); },
      move: function(){ console.log("move"); },
      end: function(){ $state.go("profile", {id: key, name: title}); },
      cancel: function(){ console.log("cancel"); }
   })
}
```

According to the docs the following things should happen:

> Once this threshold is exceeded, either the horizontal or vertical
>   delta is greater.
>
> - If the horizontal distance is greater, this is a swipe and move and end events follow.
> - If the vertical distance is greater, this is a scroll, and we let the browser take over. A cancel event is sent.

What happens is that the cancel event is sent BUT the scroll never happens. 
Is there something that I'm missing?